# Keep a history of TFS configuration

Tags: tfs

How can you version the following TFS configuration:

- Global List data XML
- Work Item Type XML

A manual workaround is to export the XML, and manually add it to TFS source control. I am wondering if there's a better way than this.

Benefit: clear history of of which configuration changed when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the solution that is recommended in the Wrox Professional TFS Books.

However, using that setup there is nothing to stop someone downloading and uploading a new version of a configuration without updating the one in version control. There are a few options you can consider if you'd like to avoid this:

1. Limit the number of people who can change process configurations.
2. Training, and hope people know that if they upload an unversioned configuration that you will come and override it with the versioned one wiping out their changes.
3. Use a build process to deploy the changes:

   - [Here is how to deploy WITD's](http://www.edsquared.com/2010/06/18/Deploying+Process+Template+Changes+Using+TFS+2010+Build.aspx) - I used to use this, but gave up because there's so few people who update the WITD's that command line imports is easier.
   - [Here's how to deploy Global Lists](http://taeguk.co.uk/blog/automating-the-deployment-tfs-global-lists/) - I developed this and use it all the time, that's because we have a large number of lists in that file and keeping Collection Admins down to a minimum is a good thing :)